# NS records, history

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I may have screwed up with some dns records, is there any site, that keeps history of dns records, where I am able to see, for example, how they looked last week?

Comment: Having once, many years ago, been burned by leaving out a . on the end of domain name, I always keep multiple versions of my dns data files.  Even for simple changes, I like to be able to roll back to a known-good version.

Answer (score 4):

Google suggests that http://dnshistory.org/ might do what you're looking for.  Revision control and backups are also good sources of information.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt dnshistory.org will provide the information you're looking for. I just checked one of my own domains, and the history it has is a bit outdated:

```
Added: 2009-10-05 Last Checked: 2010-07-23
```